# How to call the repaint() method?

Tags: phonejs

Need a code example of `repaint()` method for **dxList** widget in [Phonejs](http://phonejs.devexpress.com/)

NB: I want to call `repaint()` after a user action such as click.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the "repaint" method in the following manner:

```
<!--TRIGGER-->
<div data-bind="dxButton: { text: 'repaint dxList', clickAction: onClick }"></div>

<!--TARGET LIST-->
<div id="targetList" data-bind="dxList: { width: 100, dataSource: [{ key: 1, title: 'element_1'}, { key: 2, title: 'element_2' }, { key: 3, title: 'element_3' }] }">
    <div data-bind="dxAction: '#itemDetailsViewName/{key}'" data-options="dxTemplate : { name: 'item' } ">
        <div data-bind="text: title"></div>
    </div>
</div>

onClick: function () {
       var list = $("#targetList").dxList("instance");
       list.option('width', 200);            
       list.repaint();
}
```